# postrgresql - combine multiple updates in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two update queries:

```
update nodes set path = 'A.S' || 
case 
    when nlevel(path) > nlevel('A.C') then subpath(path, nlevel('A.C'))
    when nlevel(path) = nlevel('A.C') then ''
end
where path <@ 'A.C'



update nodes set id = 'A.S' where id = 'A.C'
```

It would be perfect if I could combine this multiple updates into one like:

```
update nodes set path = 'A.S' || 
case 
    when nlevel(path) > nlevel('A.C') then subpath(path, nlevel('A.C'))
    when nlevel(path) = nlevel('A.C') then ''
end
where path <@ 'A.C'

and

update nodes set id = 'A.S' where id = 'A.C'
```

I was looking for a possibility to do this and couldn't find,

Is it actually possible?

Would appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smth like:

```
update nodes 
  set path = 'A.S' || 
    case 
        when path <@ 'A.C' and nlevel(path) > nlevel('A.C') then subpath(path, nlevel('A.C'))
        when path <@ 'A.C' and nlevel(path) = nlevel('A.C') then ''
    else 
      path
    end
  , id = case when id = 'A.C' then 'A.S' else id end 
where path <@ 'A.C' or id = 'A.C'
```

**try in transaction - I did not test it!**